# Should the website migration be postponed to after Google major algorithm updates?

Tags: seo, migration, google-algorithm

For the major updates in Google algorithm like the recent one for medical websites, Is it better to postpone the website migration to after update launch or to speed it up to do the migration before update launch?

Comment: Does google post details of their algorithm changes ahead of time? It seems to me like they wouldn't post them until they are already rolling out, but I don't know how that process works.

Comment: Sometimes when the updates affect the SEO enormously they announce it

Comment: Both [Moz](https://moz.com/google-algorithm-change) and [Search Engine Land](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-algorithm-history/) track the major updates. It takes quite a while for Google to index sites though, so guesstimating the timing for both seems futile. If you're going to be impacted by an update, it will occur eventually. It's better to have that happen earlier than after you've spent a great deal of time on it. If you're concerned, you might review the previous changes, which would give you a better idea of the kind of things they're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate when you need to - don't worry about the Google. Google will change, tweak, introduce new algorithms...

Worry about your website's contents, make sure it's easy to navigate for the visitors. Of course, us all the appropriate tags, so that search engines can also navigate it more easily and "figure out" what's what, but that's where it ends.

Trying to "outsmart" Google, in whichever way imagineable is not a good long term strategy, nor a cost/time effective one.

As for good SEO tagging, alt descriptions, directory structure, file names etc - there's loads of info on **[google's own pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en)** and on numerous other SEO related websites.